# Simplest form not working at all

Tags: php, html, forms, xampp

Basically I'm trying to make a dummy website to show it to my client. I tried to use this simple basic form from w3school. It worked on their website but it doesn't display the echo $_POST action when I do it myself with notepad++ . Is this a problem within my computer? is there anything that I can do to fix it?

index php

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Thanks guys ! I just realized that I was dumb enough to run C:\xampp\htdocs\index.html instead of http://localhost/demo/index.html on my url.

Comment: Are you running an HTTP server (eg Apache, nginx, IIS) that knows how to execute or delegate PHP scripts? Do you have PHP installed at all on your system?

Comment: Do you use a PHP server?

Comment: Is `<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>` in your source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `php -S localhost:80`  to start a simple PHP server and listen on port 80,
if show the error: `Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: Address already in use)`, you have a web server running before.

try to enter: `http://localhost/index.php` to test if it works!

Comment: Just a note, OP will need admin rights to bind port 80. Should also point out that this command should be run in the directory containing the `.php` files

Comment: do you mean on windows, I should have admin right to bind port 80?

Comment: I think my server works just fine. I am currently running xampp with Apache port  80 & 443 and also MySQL. I run the localhost and it brings me to xampp dashboard does that mean it's working?

Comment: On any system, typically (though I could be wrong about Windows) ~ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only

Comment: nevermind. i was just dumb enough to not realize to run with http://localhost/index.html through my url

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a php server first... try xammp

Comment: I am  using xampp. both mysql and apache is running just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using a PHP server

1. Install a PHP server. I recommend XAMPP
2. Start XAMPP server
3. Create a folder inside XAMPP's htdocs folder and copy your files to it
4. In your browser Navigate to `localhost/thefolderyoumade/`